# Matlab Bar and Plot in same figure

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to put 1 bar and 2 plots in 1 figure in Matlab but there seems to be an issue with the display.

This first image shows when all 3 graphs are plotted using plot.

[image: The figure when all 3 graphs are plotted using plot]
This next image shows when the first graph is plotted using bar and the remaining using plot.
[image: When the first graph is plotted using bar and the remaining using plot]
You will notice that the 2 plots becomes very weird. There is definitely something with the rendering but i am not sure. Below is my codes used to generate these figures:

```
figure;
subplot(311);
hl = plot(time,data);datetick('x', 8);title('PIR sensor');hax=get(hl,'Parent');set(hax,'XGrid','on');
subplot(312);    
hl = plot(time,y1);datetick('x', 8);title('Gas Sensor 1');hax=get(hl,'Parent');set(hax,'XGrid','on');ylim([600 1600]);
subplot(313);
hl = plot(time,y2);datetick('x', 8);title('Gas Sensor 2');hax=get(hl,'Parent');set(hax,'XGrid','on');ylim([0 600]);
```

Comment: Could you also provide your code for the bar plots?

Comment: I just change the first plot to bar? (on line 3)

Comment: You could also include somehow the data. And please don't write the numbers in numerals (as in "put 1 bar and 2 plots in 1 figure in Matlab"), but with words, it's more clear, better written.

Comment: without testing: try to plot the bar plot at last! Not in means of appearance, just in the order of the code: `subplot(312); plot(...); subplot(313); plot(...); subplot(311); bar(...)`

Comment: @GastónBengolea The data is approx 4800 in length, I cant post it here. The data for the PIR is approx 1600. I do not think the data would affect the rendering?

Comment: @thewaywewalk I have tried putting the bar in the second or third subplot and its the same results.